# Getting NoMethodError for Padrino helper methods

Tags: ruby, helper, padrino

I'm new to Padrino and have been running through the sample blog tutorial. I'm getting a NoMethodError when using the sample code below

```
# app/views/posts/index.haml
@title = "Welcome"

#posts= partial 'posts/post', :collection => @posts
```

I tried some form helpers and they also gave the same error. The 'render' method works though. I'm using Padrino 0.9.23.

Are the Padrino helpers included automatically or do I have to?

Comment: I undeleted this post since it has been shown to be useful; someone else [solved a problem with Google's cached copy of this question](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2383713). You can delete it again if you wish, but it would be nice to leave it up for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did have to include the helpers for my app, I add the following line to the app/app.rb file just after the class definition.

```
# app/app.rb
class SampleBlog < Padrino::Application  
  register Padrino::Helpers
```

I found this out by looking at the admin/app.rb

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats correct but if you use padrino app generators, then register Padrino::Helpers is automatically added in app.rb of that app.